# How to overlay a scatter plot on a line plot in python where x axis data is string?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data as follows:

[image: A dataframe which I customised for a column day-month]

I want to plot for three different dataframes of the same kind with same no. of columns two line plot and one scatter plot( which is a smaller dataframe from the rest). The code I have used is as follows:

```
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,8))
    df1.plot(ax=axs,x='day-month', y='2015Data_Value', kind = 'scatter')

    df2.plot(ax=axs, x='day-month', y='Data_Value', linewidth=2)
    df3.plot(ax=axs, x='day-month', y='Data_Value',  linewidth=2)
```

but there is an error for scatter plot as it is not able to take x-axis value, always the error shows with 'day-month', but line plot run fine and give correct plotting when you comment out scatter plot. How does one solve such problem ?

Comment: You should try using `datetime` type instead of string type.

Comment: And if that doesn't work you could make the x integers `1, 2, 3,...` when you plot and then change the `xticklabels`

Comment: I had them as datetime over a no. of years, so I converted them to day-month string for conditional purposes, so how do I convert just day-month to datetime without adding year?